# getting current position from DataInputStream in java

Tags: java, android

Can anybody tell me how to get the current position of  the index while reading the binary file from `DataInputStream`? I have seen a `mark()` method but one is `Boolean` type and the other is `void`. I need to read the indexes on separate locations to use them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar questions have been asked before. See for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324857/javas-datainputstream-readutf-and-number-of-bytes-read).

I don't know of any better answer than this:

> A simple solution however, would be to roll your own "CountingInputStream" that extends InputStream and counts the number of bytes read. You would basically just need to override the three read-methods.

One could also implement it as a FilterInputStream directly.